# Automatic router admin password change

Tags: network, exploit, wireless

I feel that this is definitely a hack of some sort and an interesting one.

I am using a Beetel 450TC1 ADSL2+ modem router and here is what I face:
* First, I disconnect the telephone line from the modem-router, reset it and then access it using the default user/password combination.
* I just change the admin password

Now as long as I do not connect my phone cable to the modem-router I can login to http:// 192.168.1.1 using the password that I setup. The moment I connect the phone cable and as soon as the Internet LED indicator glows up, I try logging into http:// 192.168.1.1 using the user/password combination that I setup and it fails. Even the default user/password combination does not work.

I repeated this multiple times. I conclude that as long as I do not connect my phone cable; thereby accessing my DSL or the internet, my modem-router password remains unchanged.

I found a similar post here by @whitespy9:
[Router admin password was changed, how did this happen and how to prevent](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25178/router-admin-password-was-changed-how-did-this-happen-and-how-to-prevent)

My question: Have you come across such a scenario? If so, what was your solution?

Comment: Hi grammar. Im not sure i can discern what the question is that your asking...

Comment: Welcome to [security.se]. Is there a question here? Perhaps you should read the [FAQ], or the About page.

Comment: Its sounds like he is asking why/how is getting attacked through some type of drive by, with cleanup this could be salvageable question.

Comment: @AviD yeah, it's a question. I forgot to add the question part at the end. Eric G salvaged the question aptly. I'll edit my part now. Please reopen it as a question to the community

Comment: @D3C4FF Hi, I added the missing question part now.

Comment: Actually @whitespy9's problem was mistyping the IP address. His DNS servers had nothing to do with it. It is interesting what happens with your router... Actually I'd think the ISP changes it or something.